# xfs - Can't have a partition outside the disk

Tags: filesystems, partition, data-recovery, gparted, xfs

My hard drive crashed and a restoration company was able to copy everything to another new drive.

I think they used dd or similar.

It had two xfs partitions. But, now I can only mount the first one.

If I try to view the partitions with gparted it says:

```
Can't have a partition outside the disk
```

It seems that the new disk was a little smaller than the original (different models).

Update, I have confirmed my suspicion:

```
 fdisk -l -u=sectors

 Disk /dev/sdd: 9,1 TiB, 10000797794304 bytes, 19532808192 sectors
 Disk model: Elements 25A3   
 Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
 Disklabel type: gpt
 
 Device          Start         End    Sectors  Size Type
 /dev/sdd1        2048  9766436863 9766434816  4,6T Linux filesystem
 /dev/sdd2  9766436864 19532871679 9766434816  4,6T Linux filesystem
```

But the numbers doesn't match!:

```
19532808192-9766434816-9766434816-2048=63488
```

How can I update the partition table and xfs file system to fit the current hard drive?

Comment: ... if a recovery company copies a larger disk to a smaller disk, they clearly did *not* copy everything. I mean, that would be impossible. So, they basically didn't do what you paid them for.

Comment: you can't just resize your partition. The part of disk that is now missing might have contained important data. Also, as of now, XFS file systems can't be shrunk.

Comment: @MarcusMüller regarding the recovery company, they solved me the physical issue, and they are offering me alternative solutions for this issue.  I'm just trying to save time, instead of sending the disk back to them and wait

Comment: thanks @MarcusMüller Regarding possible data loss, the partition had about 30% free space. I'm not really sure if xfs is writing the sparse sectors, or if they are written more or less compactly to retrieve 99% of the data. Does xfs write compactly in preference to the beginning of the disk?

Comment: no, it does not, in general. Especially if you've only got 30% free space, it's not unlikely that every block of your disk was used at least once and might still be in use.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is with the partition table exclusively (if the filesystem itself is actually within boundaries), you can use a loop device to access the bogus partition anyway:

```
losetup --find --show --read-only --offset=$((9766436864*512)) /dev/sdx
```

If the filesystem is larger than the device, you'd have to copy it to a larger device, or emulate a larger device via the Device Mapper (dmsetup create a linear target). If you already backed up everything on `/dev/sdd1`, you can copy `/dev/sdd2` to `/dev/sdd1` then make the first partition larger.

So there are several ways to tackle this issue, but whether it will work at all will depend on how important those missing few megabytes were to the filesystem. You won't be getting those back.

Comment: thanks @frostschutz ! The filesystem is larger than the partition. So, If copy it to another thisk, and make the partition larger... how could I know what were the affected files? (those with sectors in the very last part of the partition)

Comment: You can use `filefrag -ve` or `hdparm --fibmap` to determine physical location of each file. Alternatively you could initialize the missing region with a unique data pattern then see if you can find this pattern in any of your files.